# Create private projects on stackblitz

Tags: stackblitz

How to create private projects on stackblitz on which only my team can work?
Right now anyone can access my projects .
for example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/signup

Answer (score 2):

Stackblitz now allows private repos.

Simply click on the **lock icon** (or the **settings icon**) and check the "**Make project private**" checkbox.

If you connect your github account it will create a private github repository since github now allows private repos even on the free tier.

[image]

Comment: But this is a paid feature !

Comment: @Abhishek no github has private repos now :)

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no such feature as to create a private project mark project/files as hidden.
But there is a feature request for that: https://github.com/stackblitz/core/issues/134

Comment: It has not been announced yet, but you can now mark projects as private by clicking the lock icon in the toolbar and then "Make project private"